# Can a German visa be denied due to abdominal tuberculosis, even though it is not contagious?

Tags: germany, student-visa, health

Can the German Authorities refuse to renew a Student Visa due to Abdominal Tuberculosis? How should one go about the whole process in case of this Illness!

Comment: Are you currently in Germany? Receiving treatment? Has your illness impaired your ability to progress in your studies?

Comment: I am currently in India. But i would be going back for the Interview and to complete my course. I was really ill before but now i am completely fine although under medication.

Comment: I checked the site. but this is about people in India going to Germany for the first time. I am already residing in Germany for around 2 years on a student visa. Does the same requirement apply to the Visa renewal for me? Would i be deported back from there till my illness is cured?

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to find a definitive yes or no but from the [India Education information site](http://www.indiaeducation.net/studyabroad/germany/student-visa.aspx)

> **VISA ASSESSMENT** - Applications will be assessed on the basis of the following criteria:
>
> ...
>
> - **Health Certificate:** It is essential that the applicant meets the German health requirements. This involves the proof of a recent medical check-up and an X-ray. The medical certificate should clearly identify the person examined.

So long story short if this is one of the criteria a disease like TB would probably have to be treated first before the visa can be granted.