# Can one have their German Residence Permit Renewal Interview in their home country?

Tags: germany, residence-cards

I have my German residence permit renewal interview soon. But since I am sick in my home country, can I reschedule it to be here? Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds unlikely, it's not even the same part of government handling renewals and visa applications abroad (local *Ausländerbehörde*, which is a part of the provincial and not the federal government, vs. Foreign Office). Also do make sure that staying too long abroad does not lead you to forfeit your residence permit. I don't know the exact rules for Germany but it's often necessary to be very careful with these things.

Comment: Also, if you get a refusal, it's probably beneficial to be in the country to organise an appeal, because if you are already out it might become extremely difficult to get back in.

Comment: In light of [your other question](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6222/can-a-german-visa-be-denied-due-to-abdominal-tuberculosis-even-though-it-is-not) (?), it seems there are several complications in your situation and if that's possible at all, it would seem a good idea to seek advice from a legal professional or at least from some migrant support group in Germany to avoid a negative decision that could put you in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by gala, residence permits are not processed within, or are interviews conducted at, embassies or consulates abroad. Managed by [Das Bundesamt und seine Aufgaben](http://www.bamf.de/DE/DasBAMF/dasbamf-node.html), interviews are conducted by Ausländerbehörde, according to locale.

Asking for a residence renewal when you are not in Germany, but in your home country on medical leave and receiving treatment (per your separate question), makes it unlikely that the an extension/renewal would be considered. With an illness that has postponed your return to Germany (and may necessitate a new medical exam and certificate), you should contact your school to confirm that you are still enrolled, that your visa status hasn’t been affected by your absence, and that you’re are still eligible to renew residence.